# Particle Choice: は・が・を - "I want ... to be my ..."

Tags: particles

(私は)山田先生**が**私の指導教員になってもらってほしいのでメールを書いています。

I am trying to say: "I hope Yamada Sensei could be my advisor, so I'm writing this mail."

In this situation, is が the correct particle?

Comment: Are you writing this to 山田先生 or to a third party? Because I don't think the particle is the only problem here..

Comment: @virmaior I'm writing to 山田先生.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct particle to use there is 「に」.  Another possibility is 「と」, but 「に」 would be far more common.  Some children might use 「が」, but they, too, will grow out of it in time.

> 「(person) + **に** + (thing/position) + **に** + なってもらう」　=  "to have (person) become a/my (thing/position)"

I actually see a huge problem in the middle part of your sentence.  Not sure if I should correct it, but 「なってもらってほしい」 makes no sense.

It is 「なってほしい」 or 「なってもらいたい」 for grammatical correctness, but because those lack any respect for the teacher, you would want to say:　「なっていただきたい」

> 「[山田先生]{やまだせんせい}**に**[指導教員]{しどうきょういん}**に**なっていただきたく、メールをお[送]{おく}りしています。」